# Eclipse: Two Linked Resources pointing to same physical file are opening twice in Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I had to create multiple [linked resources](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-13.htm) pointing to a single physical file in an Eclipse project. The problem is, whenever I try to open these two files, the editor opens each file in a separate tab, it won't direct me to the already opened file.

This is different from how VisualStudio works. VisualStudio has an option to add an existing file to a project. A single file can be used in multiple projects. Whenever we open both files, VS will direct us to the already opened file, it won't open the file in a new tab.

It's possible that developers open/edit multiple files at the same time and not notice that the same physical file was opened more than once. This behavior can potentially cause a lot of problems, for example, if File 1 is modified but not saved, and later File 2 is modified then saved, all modifications previously done in File 1 will be lost.

Is there any preference to turn-off/on this behavior? If not, can I implement this hook as a plugin?

Comment: I checked how this works in VisualStudio. It's simple, they call it as "existing file". We can still make a single file part of many projects. It stores the information in some xml files related to VS, similar to Eclipse. When it comes to editor, when I open both of them, the IDE directs me to the already opened file, instead of opening it in another tab. I wonder why Eclipse won't work that way...!

Comment: There is one difference between VS and Eclipse though. In eclipse, you can rename the resource to something else, i.e., you can have different names for the same physical resource similar to symlinks in unix. In VS, we can't rename the files when adding existing files.